# jQuery - output this list of objects in 3 columns

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone tell me how to output this list of objects in 3 columns and sort the list alphabetically? I tried `else if` but...

CSS:

```
.main {
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    background:#9c9;
}
.center {
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    background:#c9c;
}
```

HTML:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = [
            {name: "Dan", age: 25, desc: "test"}, 
            {name: "Aary", age: 15, desc: "description"},
            {name: "Bary", age: 15, desc: "description"},
            {name: "Cary", age: 15, desc: "description"},
            {name: "Dary", age: 15, desc: "description"},
            {name: "Fary", age: 15, desc: "description"},
            {name: "Tom", age: 18, desc: "haaha"}
        ];

        function findName(personName){
            return $.grep(data, function(item){
              return item.name == personName;
            });
        }

        function details(personName)
        {
            var person = findName(personName.toString())[0];
            $('#description').html(person.desc);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class='main'>
        </div>
        <div class='center'>
        </div>
        <div id="description">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            $('.main').append("<a onclick='javascript:details(\"" + data[i].name + "\")'>" + data[i].name + " <strong>(" + data[i].age + ")</strong>" + "</a></br>");
        } else {
            $('.center').append("<a onclick='javascript:details(\"" + data[i].name + "\")'>" + data[i].name + " <strong>(" + data[i].age + ")</strong>" + "</a></br>");
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KKYZj/8/

Comment: what should be in 3rd column?

Comment: It should be "dynamic". For example if I have A, B, C. A should be 1 column, B second, C third.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add another div column: `<div class='right'></div>`

And then change your javascript to:

```
$(function () {

    data.sort(function (a, b) { return a.name > b.name; });

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        var target = [$('.main'), $('.center'), $('.right')][i % 3];
        target.append("<a onclick='javascript:details(\"" + data[i].name + "\")'>" + data[i].name + " <strong>(" + data[i].age + ")</strong>" + "</a></br>");
    }
});
```

Comment: Or use `data.sort(function (a, b) { return a.name.localeCompare(b.name); });` if you're wanting unicode sorting.

Comment: Could you tell me is there any way so I can sort them like A first column B below, C second column D below, E third column?

Comment: You'll want to replace `[i % 3]` with `[parseInt(i / data.length * 3)]`

Comment: Man you are GREAT! I can't thank you enough!!! I will try to learn all of this (but it's hard) and be like you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Look [`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/KKYZj/15/).

Ok. I put all data items in same containers with `float: left;` property. When need to break line and start new row of items we put `<br style="clear: both">` element depending on condition `if(i%3 == 0)` where `3` is column count. Also I modified click handlers for elements.

js:

```
    var data = [
            {name: "Dan", age: 25, desc: "test"}, 
            {name: "Aary", age: 15, desc: "description"},
            {name: "Bary", age: 15, desc: "description"},
            {name: "Cary", age: 15, desc: "description"},
            {name: "Dary", age: 15, desc: "description"},
            {name: "Fary", age: 15, desc: "description"},
            {name: "Tom", age: 18, desc: "haaha"}
        ];

        function findName(personName){
            return $.grep(data, function(item){
              return item.name == personName;
            });
        }

$(function() {
    for(var i=1;i<data.length;i++)
    {        
        var dataItem = "<a href='#' class='dataItem' data-description='" + data[i].desc + "'>" + data[i].name + " <strong>(" + data[i].age + ")</strong>" + "</a>";
            $('.main').append(dataItem);

        if(i%3 == 0) {
         $('.main').append("</br>")   ;
        }
    }

    var description = $('#description');
    $('a.dataItem').on('click', function(e){
        description.text($(this).data('description'));
    })
});
```

html:

```
<div>
    <div class='main'>
    </div> 
    <div id='description'></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.main a{
display: block;
float:left;
width:150px;
background:#9c9;
}
```

Don`t need to put js code and html, body, head tags in html area

Comment: Please *explain* the changes you made. You didn't even include the code in your answer.

Comment: Thank you! This looks great, but I need to display description when they click name below objects. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/KKYZj/13/)

Comment: Thank you YD so much! I would like to mark you're answer as useful, but I don't have enough points :(